# Serve Static JSON file from public folder in Next JS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a folder structure like below and want to fetch the data from the API folder(static JSON files) and use them in the "element" folder. I know I can directly use images without mentioning the URL. How can I achieve my requirement?

PS: I don't want to create a data folder and place my JSON data there and import it as a file (it will build the entire project if I change any data in that JSON.

```
Folder Structure:
--elements
--Public
  |_ API
    |_data.json
  |_ Images
```

Comment: _"without mentioning the URL"_ - what do you mean?

Comment: If I want to use images from public folder I can directly use <img src={"/images/pic1.jpg"} /> like this  right... I was referring to that

Comment: In next, can you not add a public folder, but the image in there and use it? https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand your question

Comment: Have you read and followed the instructions on the page I linked?

Comment: yes, I did just now. so according to that, I can add any static file in the public folder unless it has the same name as that of a page name right?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the particular use-case is already covered in docs cited above.

Comment: Yes. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/conflicting-public-file-page

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I understand that part, but just clarify this: If I create a file name data.json in the public folder and don't have any pages with the same name, how can I use the data in data.json on one of my pages?

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching